# Update USGS maps services reference?

Tags: wms, usgs

I was accessing USGS map services at http://isse.cr.usgs.gov/ArcGIS/services/Combined/SDDS_Imagery/MapServer/WMSServer, through a program.

This link no longer works. I found a redirect - that took me to http://viewer.nationalmap.gov/example/services.html.

What would be a replacement site for the one I was using ?

Comment: What was the WMS you were using?

Comment: yes, but I can't find that in the new reference list

Comment: Something like this?? [Accessing High Resolution Orthoimagery (HRO) Map Services](http://seamless.usgs.gov/service_access_list.php?serviceid=Dataset_7&dataset=HRO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new location for **SDDS Imagery** is :

**http://raster.nationalmap.gov/ArcGIS/services/Orthoimagery/SDDS_Imagery/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS**